# Angular + Nativescript web and mobile development

Tags: angular, mobile, nativescript, angular2-template, angular2-nativescript

We have a developed a full Angular4 web app and now we're deciding to move towards mobile application, but we have some doubts regarding NativeScript.

1. What's the best strategy to have the same codebase (actual Angular project) with NativeScript integrated? The goal is not duplicate the components but switch between xml or html depending on the platform.
2. We could observe that some modules have specific implementations in NativeScript, for example: Router module, is there a way of using the same router for the application? Or we switch between modules for web or mobile platforms.
3. We are concerned about NativeScript community, we could see very few medium/large companies using apps developed in NativeScript in contrast to React Native which is used by Tesla, Airbnb, Instagram, ... Are there some real good showcases for NativeScript
4. We are using Socket.IO we want to know whether NativeScript could be integrated with Socket and with push notifications.
5. What would be the best directory layout for both codes coexistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can checkout a this repos:

   https://github.com/jlooper/angular-starter

   https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed

   https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

   All of them have the same objective, to share the same code base between the web and mobile and even desktop
2. Yes you have to use two different modules for web and mobile, but you can easily do it with angular dependency injection system(check the seeds's above)
3. Nativescript is also used by big companies [check this out](https://www.nativescript.org/showcases)
4. Yes it can ;) [check this out](http://market.nativescript.org/) also you have other plugins to work with notifications.
5. Check the seeds :)